# IEEEeqnarray and space for equation number

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations, ieeetran

I am using IEEEeqnarray to align long equations, but it seems it won't consider the width of the equation reference number when performing the aligningment, despite the documentation clearly stating "\IEEEeqnarray automatically adds a hidden column for equation numbering" (IEEEtrantools documentation, page 19).

My mwe, made just to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\section{testing}

testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some  

\setcounter{equation}{110}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\int_{\Omega_{V^*}} \!\!\!\!\nabla \tilde{u} \cdot \nabla \varphi \;d\Omega - \int_{\Gamma_{V^*}} \!\!\!\!K_H\, \varphi\, \delta V\cdot \hat{n} \;d\Gamma &=& \int_{\Omega_{V^*}}\!\!\! f \varphi \;d\Omega + \int_{\Gamma_{V^*}}\!\!\! g\,\varphi \;d\Gamma
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega_{V^*}} \!\!\!\!\nabla \tilde{u} \cdot \nabla \varphi \;d\Omega - \int_{\Gamma_{V^*}} \!\!\!\!K_H\, \varphi\, \delta V\cdot \hat{n} \;d\Gamma = \int_{\Omega_{V^*}}\!\!\! f \varphi \;d\Omega + \int_{\Gamma_{V^*}}\!\!\! g\,\varphi \;d\Gamma
\end{equation}
testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some stuff testing some  

\end{document}
```

The output of the above is the following:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the  equation environment properly considers the space taken by the equation number, while IEEEeqnarray seems not to do it.

Any suggestion on how to handle this?

Thank you,
Filippo

Comment: `\rule{5cm}{2mm} &=& \rule{6cm}{2mm}` confirms that like the normal `eqnarray` the equation number is not moved if the line is too long. Exactly where is it mentioned that `IEEEeqnarray` should be able to move the eqn number? I cannot find any documentation that has a page 19

Comment: @daleif: here: http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf
At the very end of Page 19.

EDIT: I never said that the equation number should be moved. Instead, the positioning of the equation itself should take into consideration the space occupied by the equation number, exactly like the "equation" environment does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be some confusion over what the expression "`\IEEEeqnarray` automatically adds a hidden column for equation numbering" means in practice. To my reading of the user guide, it simply means that care is taken not to let the math material "overlap" with the equation number. (By the way, this type of overlap is a well-known problem of the deprecated `eqnarray` environment. Indeed, the overlap issue is just one of several reasons for why `eqnarray` is considered deprecated and should no longer be used.)

The expression does *not* mean, though, that the resulting row will be centered in the exact same way as would be the case if it (the whole equation) had been entered directly as an `equation` environment. To achieve the latter effect, it's necessary to insert the directive `\IEEEeqnarraynumspace` on every row that's supposed to receive the special centering treatment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{110}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\int_{\Omega_{V^*}} \mkern-12mu\nabla \tilde{u} \cdot \nabla \varphi \,\mathrm{d}\Omega 
-\int_{\Gamma_{V^*}} \mkern-12muK_H\, \varphi\, \delta V\cdot \hat{n} \,\mathrm{d}\Gamma 
&=& \int_{\Omega_{V^*}}\mkern-12mu f \varphi \,\mathrm{d}\Omega 
+\int_{\Gamma_{V^*}}\mkern-12mu g\,\varphi \,\mathrm{d}\Gamma
\IEEEeqnarraynumspace % <--- this is new
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\hrule
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega_{V^*}} \mkern-12mu\nabla \tilde{u} \cdot \nabla \varphi \,\mathrm{d}\Omega 
-\int_{\Gamma_{V^*}} \mkern-12muK_H\, \varphi\, \delta V\cdot \hat{n} \,\mathrm{d}\Gamma 
= \int_{\Omega_{V^*}}\mkern-12mu f \varphi \,\mathrm{d}\Omega 
+\int_{\Gamma_{V^*}}\mkern-12mu g\,\varphi \,\mathrm{d}\Gamma
\end{equation}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!
I was under the impression that reserving a column for the equation number would produce exactly that effect, so that the equation itself would be centered in the remaining space thanks to the hidden "+" glue delimiter that ends the declaration of the columns.
Indeed, with your suggestion it looks so much better.